# Can I hide iAds once they are tapped?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios4, iad

I was wondering wether I can hide iAds once they are tapped. This way, once the user taps on the ad, he can get rid of it. It will draw incentive to tapping on the ads to get rid of them. All I am doing different is hiding the iAd banner when the 'bannerViewDidFinish' method is called. Is this ok to do? I know that I can't get another ad displayed until the user restarts the app, but I am ok with that. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You should *really* accept some answers before asking a new one.

Comment: Why would you want to force the closing of an ad banner?  The user has a perfectly good way of closing it at any time via the X at the corner of the ad screen.  As fluchtpunkt points out, if you're using this to game the system in terms of ad impressions, that will not fly  with Apple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at rule 7.1 of the [App Store Review Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html).

> Apps that artificially increase the number of impressions or click-throughs of ads will be rejected

Imho "It will draw incentive to tapping on the ads to get rid of them." is covered by this rule.

Answer (score 1):

[banner hide] or banner.hidden = YES under a touchesBegan mehod or put an invisible button over the ad or a no imaged uiiamgeview and implement pressed button or touched image